# Dreamweaver Delete Space to Word, Not Word

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing, dreamweaver

There's a built in DW keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + Del) that deletes up to AND INCLUDING the first word to the right. I used to use the ColdFusion Studio app for coding and it would just remove the space UP TO the word (left the word or bracket, or whatever alone.)

Any DW users know if this is a setting that can be changed? I'm really used to the old behavior and keep deleting the first word, hitting Ctrl + Z to put it back and then having to manually delete all the spaces to leave the word...

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found a way to approximate what you're looking for.

```
Ctrl + Shift + Right/Left    "Select Until Next/Previous Word"
```

Using the keyboard shortcut above you can select from the cursor up to the next or previous word.

In practice, it appears to also select the next/previous word sometimes. But, you can use the opposite direction arrow to fine tune your selection.

So, if you use Ctrl + Shift + Right to select up to the next word and it also selects the next word, simply hit Ctrl + Shift + Left to remove that word from the selection.

Then hit delete.

It's not as simple a solution as you were looking for, but it should be better than what you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe have topic on editing the Keyboard Shortcuts here:

[help.adobe.com/...](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Extending/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d117f508c8de-7feb.html)

It helped me with Menu Commands, but not so sure about builtin shortcuts. Try it out.